# How to save Notifications in Amazon DynamoDB directly from AWS SNS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created Lambda endpoints and subscribed to SNS, i created the SES and tested the message that saves in the dynamoDB through lambda, for the same SES when i send APNS_SANDBOX json format from lambda still it saves in dynamoDB, but i want to save the notifications from SNS Topic, when i send the notification from topic it do not save in the dynamoDB, i have given all the policies and permissions in IAM.
Please help me to solve this issue. can i have a complete details on saving the notifications in dynamoDB from SNS topic?

Comment: can some one reply please?

Comment: DynamoDB Documentation sucks ...... Very bad respond from their developers.